# mockito a List<Predicate<String>> to always return true

Tags: java, list, mockito, predicate

I have a list<Predicate> which is a private field of a class, and this field will be used to filter lines of data.

I would like to test my class with mocking the list<Predicate> by making it always true/false.

```
public class T {
     private final List<Predicate<String>> filters;
     
     public void run(){
         ...
         while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
              if (filters.stream().allMatch(filter -> filter.test(line))) {
               ....
}}}
```

I am wondering how to mock this field filters in tests. Thanks!

Comment: How and where are the filters created? I would not mock a list, or a predicate. These are simple things and you should be able to just provide instances of them. For example, set the list to a single predicate that just returns true. `when(provider.getFilters()).thenReturn(List.of(s -> true));` No need for mocks.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, which makes sense to me. It eases my headache.